# Enabling Kinect In a Browser using NaCl

Tags: kinect-sdk, google-nativeclient

While working on a project with the kinect, I had an idea of integrating it onto a web browser directly from the device. I was wondering if someone has done this before or if there exists some form of information that can shed some light.

In More Detail:
I've been dissecting the Kinect Fusion application that is provided with the kinect and I was wondering what it would take to have a browser do a direct to device 3d scanning. I've discovered NaCl which claims that it can run native code, but I don't know how well it would run Microsoft native code (from the Kinect SDK version 2 //what I'm using.) also just looking at NaCl with no prior experience(with NaCl), I currently cannot imagine what steps to take to actually activate the kinect and have it start feeding the image render to the browser.

I know there exists some libraries that allow the kinect to work on other operating systems and was wondering if those libraries would allow me to have a general bitmapping to send the pp::graphics2d stuff for nacl(for the image display), for which I would then need to figure out how to actually present that onto the browser itself then have it run the native code in the background to create the 3d image then save it to the local computer.

I figured "let me tap the power of the stack." I'm afraid of an overflow, but you can't break eggs without making a few omelettes. Any information would be appreciated! If more information is needed, ask and I shall try my best to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unlikely to work, as Native Client doesn't allow you to access OS-specific libraries.

Here's a library which uses NPAPI to allow a web page to communicate with the native kinect library: https://github.com/doug/depthjs. NPAPI will be deprecated soon, so this is not a long-term solution.

It looks like there is an open-source library for communicating with the kinect: https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect. It would be a decent amount of work, but it looks like it should be possible to reverse-engineer the protocol from this library and perform the communication in JavaScript, via the [chrome.usb apis](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/usb).

Comment: Thank you for the information :) I'll look into this right away! I'll post any updates as they come.

Answer (score 0):

Try EuphoriaNI. The library and some samples are available at http://kinectoncloud.com/. Currently, only the version for AS3 is posted on the site though. The version for the Web, of course, requires you to install a service on your computer (it's either that or a browser plug-in... and nobody likes those :)